# Ckeditor dialogs input field disabled when editor itself placed in modal

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, ckeditor, material-ui

I am using material-ui-next dialog. As a editor i am using ckeditor and placing it in the modal. To add latex text i used MathJax plugin. 
While adding latex i am not able to focus the input to right latex in mathjax pop-up

Any react solution is appreciated, i am not using JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is old but I was facing the same problem and solved adding `disableEnforceFocus` prop inside the "Dialog" tag.

```
<Dialog disableEnforceFocus>
```